# Write a File into the App Bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsbundle

I have a Webservice to download some News and write them into a plist-file somewhere in `NSLibraryDirectory`, thats fine. But if the user has no Internet connection or the webservice is offline or whatever, I load a Default-Newsfile from within the AppBundle.

At the moment I have to replace the Default-File manually before every AppStoreUpdate to keep it up to date.

My Question: Is there an easy way to write into the App Bundle while debugging via Simulator, so the Default-File will everytime be up to date.

I tought about something like:

```
#ifdef SIMULATOR
   //Write to AppBundle
#endif
```

**Note:**
It's all about the time while I use the Mac and the Simulator, I don't want to do that in the Published App!
Yes, I already replace the Ressource in my Bundle, but by hand and I want it to realize automatically.
I want to keep my Projectfolder up to date, before I compile it for any Device or the AppStore.

Comment: The question is not clear. Is this what you want - when running in debug mode, download news from internet and save it into a file that can later be *shipped* as part of app bundle?

Comment: Exactly, but I don't want to copy anything from Documents to my projectfolder, so I can share the project with my co-workers without any explanation. And nobody will forget to Update the newsfiles in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on your comment, here's what you need (I think - still not completely clear on the question, but let me know if this works for you).

- Create an empty file (say news.plist) in your project folder (SRCROOT). Add this to your repo.
- Add this file in your project's resources and add it in `Copy Bundle Resources` step in `Build Phases`
- When you download content from internet, save it to project's temporary folder, then copy it to SRCROOT/news.plist overwriting existing file (optionally add a check on file checksum to avoid unnecessary change). This step is required ONLY when running on simulator.
- Whenever developers check-in, the updated news.plist should be checked in to the repo.

To make SRCROOT available in code, add `SRCROOT=\"${SRCROOT}\"` to GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS.

Other developer won't need to do anything except the last step - check in the updated file every time it changes.

Does this help?

Comment: In your Point 3: "then copy it to SRCROOT/news.plist", that's what I'm struggling with. How to do this automatically? How to access SRCROOT in a function or what other kind of magic is needed to do this?

Comment: That's it, thank you. Such a big trouble and the answer is just that simple.

Answer (score 7):

`AppBundle` is `Read-only` you cannot write anything to it programmatically, however if you update the resources in your `Project` through `Xcode`, you get the updated file automatically in the `AppBundle`..

Comment: While on the Mac with the Simulator I should be able to write wherever I want, or not? I dont't talk about the published App!

Comment: No where, you cannot write on any device.. AppBundle is read-only.. It will just fail.. By the way you can put your Default file in `Documents Directory` it is Read-Write, you can update the file there in that folder easily programmatically..

Comment: I never said that I want to write on a Device.

Comment: Yes I think you can write file in your Mac's `Desktop` or, `Documents` folder, and access them.. But make sure you create a separate folder to write your data, so that in anycase it will not corrupt your root folder..

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but instead of `Documets` I want the Projectfolder like `${SRCROOT}` or something.

Answer (score 1):

No, you might be possible to get the simulator to write to you App Bundle, but this does not mean that the file your project (the one that gets compiled when you build for the app store) will be updated.

Why not just save the new to the documents directory, then always load this file. After the app is started, start a background thread and try to update the plist file. Of you are successful in retrieving the news over the write the plist file in the document directory.
This way the user will have an file that was retrieved the last time the device was able to get the file.

You could add an file in the app bundle which you copy to the documents directory on first start of the application, just to make sure that the user has data in the app.

Comment: Yea, thats what I'm already doing. I have a "default"-Plist in the app bundle and I do it more or less like you said, but I would prefer to write or copy the file directly to the correct Folder automatically while debugging, so I wouldn't forget it sometime.

Comment: Then you will have to use some kind of precompile script.